# SVN Netbeans - Resolve conflicts - keep both versions

Tags: svn, netbeans, svn-merge

I'm using SVN with latest Netbeans. Is it possible to keep both changes when resolving a conflicts? Using netbeans or svn command line?

I have 2 branches, both have file main.java. One developer adds there function funA() in branch 1 and other adds funB() in branch 2. Next I merge both branches to trunk and I get conflict in main.java, but I'd like to save both functions not only one.

Comment: that highly depends on type of the conflicts......

Comment: Are you looking for something like `svn merge` ([doc](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re16.html))?

Comment: I have the same issue. Netbeans merge tool has a big defect - it allows to accept only one of the sites to put to the resulting merge. It's weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manual merge using mergetools. Which answer you want to see?

[More on Merge Conflicts](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced.mergeconflicts) may be useful (and all chapter "Advanced Merging" from first to last chars also). And in case of CLI-merge without mergetools conflicted both parts stored (decorated) in file